# Mailing labels witth membership status or expiration date

Tags: civimail, civimember, mailing

So we use Civi for a magazine subscription or rather we are intending to do that. The hiccup at the moment is since it is a magazine we cannot print a separate sheet for the subscribers expiration date as that is not possible, so we want to add that to the mailing label that we do print. We have tried adding the extension https://github.com/ginkgostreet/com.ginkgostreet.relatedmembershiptokens/ but that is for emails and does not work in the mailing label part. Unfortunately hundres of our subscribers have not updated us with their email and still send in checks, so we are trying to accommodate them while new subscribers we have email addresses for. In any case has anyone been able to add these features to a mailing label?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to Membership end date than probably you could use [Fuzion tokens extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fuzion-tokens), it should give you membership end date token, which you can insert in mailing label

Comment: pretty sure that is how we have done in past, in fact it may have been the first requirement that triggered that extension being built

Answer (score 1):

We've been doing something similar for 5+ years on our Wordpress installation.

1. In your contact layout, create a custom field for expiration date.
2. At CiviCRM/Administer CiviCRM/Address Settings, add something like this as
   the first line of your labels (i.e., before the name and address
   tokens). Note that this first line is **standardized text combined with
   your CiviCRM-defined custom field number**.

   Thanks for subscribing through {contact.custom_52}
3. This will show your message and the date as the first line of their label.